# How can I troubleshoot vertical bands in photo prints from my Epson printer?

Tags: troubleshooting, printing

I have an Epson R1900 printer. These bands seem to line up with ridges on the carrier(?!) I don’t know how that could happen, but I have done everything! Numerous head cleanings, head alignment, etc. Nozzles are clean.

Colors are beautiful, and the test print shows good. But whenever I print larger than an 8x10, using the correct settings to match the paper (Epson paper), I get these bands. In this photo you can see the thicker lines, but there are thinner lines in between.

I’ve tried printing using best photo, photo, and I unchecked the high-speed box. It also doesn’t matter what print app I’m using, be it Lightroom or Epson Easy Photo.

I did get a few good prints befoe this started happening. Could it be pressing the paper too hard against the carrier and picking up its marks?

[image: Sample print displaying bands]

Comment: When asking for troubleshooting help, it's generally a good idea to explain what equipment you're deal with. I can infer that it's a printer, and perhaps one made by Epson, but that doesn't narrow it down much. Why make us guess?

Comment: Omg, I can’t believe I left that out . Thank, I issued an edit!

Comment: What is the resolution of the images you are printing? What is the native resolution of the R1900?

Comment: If all of the bands were darker than the surrounding image, I'd say "clean the rollers, which have somehow gotten ink on them." But some of the bands are darkers and some of them are lighter.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. I think I know what’s going on now, just not sure why. The marks are definitely coming from the bottom of the carriage, and it seens to be from excessive ink.  I’m going to clean that ink pad again & see what happens. I need to figure out why thete’s a saturation of ink.